# Outputting From Resource File

Tags: asp.net, webforms

So I am working on localization for a website, and I have ran into many scenarios where I need to output the localized string from the resource, such as in the following markup:

```
<cc1:TabPanel HeaderText="<%= Culture.Strings.labelImageA %>">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <img id="ImageA" runat="server"/>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc2:Charter ID="CharterA" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</cc1:TabPanel>
```

In the instance above, I am attempting to output form the resource `Culture.Strings.labelImageA` but am receiving a warning that

> This is not a scriplet.Will be output as plain text

Is there an escape character I can use in the markup in order to allow this to pull from the resource file?  Otherwise, I will have to jump through many hoops to set this property in the code behind.

Comment: what kind of hoops? maybe this can be encapsulated into it's own object, then you only need to work with the fascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What surely works is to use binding markup `<%# %>`. This, however, would probably require calling `DataBind` manually on your control.

I doubt there exists a simpler way.